# Is there a more Angular Way to get dynamically added modal html into a page than append()?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This directive works, but I'm trying to see if there's a more "Angular way" to load separate modals files, compile them into a single block, then get them into the DOM.

I've created a Style Guide that loads individual html fragments into the "concept" and "sample" sections. In the "sample" sections, I occasionally have Bootstrap modals that are a separate file for each particular section.

Right now, if a user navigates to a section or subsection I'm checking to see if a modal file exists for that section ($http.get), and if they do, I'm element.append(ing) them after initially emptying the element's html().

I *think* it would be more Angular to somehow compile an object that has all the html and have that be the bound content, i.e., {{compiledHtml}} but I can't figure out a way to do that.

For a subsection, it loads just that one modal file. For a section, it loads all the modal files in the subsections.

For example, styleguide/colors would load all the modals in all subsections, but styleguide/colors/main would only load the modals file Colors_Main_Modals.html

Any suggestions about (a) is it better to do it another way than I am, (b) if it's the compile and bind method, how to do that, and (c) any other ideas?

**DATA EXAMPLE:**

```
  {
    "order":2,
    "section":"Colors",
    "subsections":[
      "Overview",
      "Main Palette",
      "Extended Palette",
      "Shades",
      "Grays"
    ]
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div modals-view></div>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive( 'modalsView', ['$route', '$http', 'dataStore', function ( $route, $http, dataStore ) {
    return {
        restrict  : 'A',
        scope     : true,
        controller: function ( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {

        },
        link      : function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            // check if there's a modals file for that route, if so, use it, otherwise load blank page
            // if it's a section only, include all modals

            function appendModals(sectionToAdd){

                $http.get( 'app/content/' + $route.current.params.section + '_' + sectionToAdd.replace(/ /g,"_") + '_Modals.html' )
                    .success(
                    function ( data ) {
                       element.append( data );
                    } )
                    .error(
                    function () {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                );
            }

            scope.$on( '$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                element.html("");
                scope.isSubsection = $route.current.params.subsection ? true : false;

                dataStore.async().then( function ( d ) {
                    scope.allmodals = _.filter( d.data, function ( obj ) {
                        return obj.section == $route.current.params.section;
                    } );

                    if ( $route.current.params.subsection ) {
                        appendModals($route.current.params.subsection);
                    } else {
                        $.each( scope.allmodals[0].subsections, function ( i ) {
                            appendModals(scope.allmodals[0].subsections[i]);
                        } );
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }
    }
}] );
```

Comment: seems like a lot of extra work when angular already has `$templateCache` and fetching templates is already built in using `templateUrl` or directive like `ng-include` which can use a dynamic source. Don't see why you need to load all the modals and not use them on demand. Take a look at how angular-ui-bootstrap modals work

Comment: I am using them on demand. There are dozens of sections, each with a number of subsections. I only load the modals that are either in the section (for a section view) or in the subsection (for a subsection view).

Comment: The sections and subsections are separate directives with includes (not shown) expressed on the main page via $route and ng-view

Comment: point I'm getting at by `on demand` is get it only if user needs it. If it's already in templateCache also there won't be need to make another request

Comment: So, looking at $templateCache, is there a way to add multiple separate templates to a single instance?